# Azure DevOps Server 2020.0.2 vs 2020.1.2

Tags: azure-devops

I'm a little confused over the latest released versions of Azure DevOps Server 2020 on 17th May.

What is the difference between 2020.0.2 and 2020.1.2 and why are two versions of 2020 being maintained?

Currently running 2020.0.1 and looking to move to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference should between Server Version RC and RTW. The data migration tool doesn't support imports from Azure DevOps Server release candidates (RC). If you're planning on importing your collection database to Azure DevOps Services using this service, it's important that you don't upgrade your production database to an RC release. If you do upgrade, then you will need to wait and upgrade to the release to web (RTW) version when it's available or restore a backup copy of your database from a previous Azure DevOps Server version to import.

From the Release on May 17, 2022, along with several fixes, the Data Migration tool will be available for both Sever 2020.0.2 and 2020.1.2

[image]

[image]

Before preparing for upgrade, check this official doc: [Upgrade your deployment - Azure DevOps Server & TFS | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops-2020)